# What does これでチャラにしとくよ means?

Tags: meaning

I'am currently reading a manga, there is this sentence "これでチャラにしとくよ". I don't really get it. Please translate, thank you

Comment: Related:  See @cypher's answer here https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5094/what-does-%e3%83%81%e3%83%a3%e3%83%a9-mean/5098#5098

Answer (score 3):

It means something like "I'll let you off the hook (with this)".

Either the speaker (let's call him A) had previously done some favor for the other person (B) and B had just returned the favor, or alternatively, B had previously done something to anger A, and in this case, A had just "paid it back" by punishing B. Either way, what A is saying is either "now, neither of us owes the other one anything" or "no more grudges".

This relates to the second definitions on [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%89-566977) and [大辞林第三版](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%89-566977).