# 彼氏・彼女 pitch accent

Tags: pitch-accent, kansai-ben

I have always thought in 標準語 those two words should always be 頭高, as corroborated by several authoritative sources including NHK. But I have very occasionally heard other pitch patterns. [This one](https://youtu.be/dO8eR4zz3RY) sounds clearly to me like 平板: かれしが{LHHH}. Why is that? Also, what about 彼女? Is it ever realized as 平板?

An additional question is: how are they pronounced in 関西弁? Because I talk with people from 関西 a lot and they switch back and forth between dialects, which makes it hard for me to be certain if their pronunciation is standard.

Comment: FYI https://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~QM4H-IIM/k031004.htm

Answer (score 3):

The heiban versions have been common for decades, but still sound more or less frivolous or チャラい (more so for カノジョ than カレシ). A professional seiyu should be able use the two pronunciations appropriately depending on the character being played. See: [Are there any rules to the intonations they are discussing in this video?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74609/5010)

I feel both patterns are in use also in Kansai-ben, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I have been looking for instances of 彼女 online. I found some instances of 彼女さん that sound to me like a heiban 彼女: [1](https://youtu.be/1fZUpFS69tQ); [2](https://youtu.be/tKDkuqFsauE?t=211); [3](https://youtu.be/n0YNizSCY30?t=660); [4](https://youtu.be/2LL3yq7hdhc?t=1800). I don't know if I should update the question or put them in a new question but I wonder if I'm hearing them right and if they are standard. [5](https://youtu.be/dF-onvlL57A?t=394) This one I'm not sure about. When they first talk about 彼女 it sounds like 頭高 but when the interviewer says 彼女さん it sounds to me like かのじょさん{HHHHH}

Comment: @EddieKal Yes 1-4 are heiban and 5 is atamadaka. Both patterns are common, with our without さん.