# What's the difference between お調子者 and かっこつけ?

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between お調子者 and かっこつけ? Please give me examples.

Answer (score 2):

These are fundamentally different words. A stereotypical [ちゃらい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5094/5010) person may have both traits, though.

**お調子者** refers to a frivolous and talkative person who does not have their own opinion and readily chimes in with others. An お調子者 likes to survive by flattering someone or being flattered by someone.

**かっこつけ** is someone who tries hard to appear or act cool. It can imply the person is empty inside and does not have an ability that matches their appearance.