# Meanings and etymology of the word キザ

Tags: etymology

There's a character in this game whose bio describes him as a "キザでお調子者な優男", which I currently understand to mean "pretentious, kind man who tends to get carried away easily." Problem is that キザ as "pretentious" according to [jisho](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B0%97%E9%9A%9C) seems to contradict the rest of the bio referring to him as being likable and friendly, so I know there's something up with キザ. While looking at EN translations of キザ in VN scripts that I have, I frequently see it as "exaggerated", "show-off", "flashy", and "melodramatic" that seem to fit better with the bio. So then, what exactly is the origin of this word?

Comment: 優男 Doesn't necessarily mean kind, it usually means elegant and slender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in that entry, キザ is 気障 in kanji, so its origin is [気に障る](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B0%97%E3%81%AB%E9%9A%9C%E3%82%8B) ("nerve-touching") or "annoying". However, in modern Japanese, "annoying" is no longer the primary meaning of the word.

Today, it describes something excessively dramatic or romantic (often to the point of sounding either funny or cringeworthy). キザな台詞 refers to something like a cliché line you might hear in an old romantic movie (like [this](https://www.cookdoor.jp/useful/glossary/izakaya/2589901/)). Stereotypically, a キザな人間 is a male person who tries to appear cool and refined, prefers to wear formal attire, utters such lines unabashedly, and does not hesitate to present roses to women. Being キザ tends to be seen negatively, especially by other males, but it's used neutrally, too. Being キザでお調子者 might also mean being a [チャラ男](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5094/5010).

By the way, 優男【やさおとこ】 does not mean "gentleman" or "kind man". Please read [this](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E5%84%AA%E7%94%B7).